# Does the usual law for image also hold for relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, relations

Let $R \subseteq U \times V$ be a relation, and $S_0, \dots, S_{m-1} \subseteq U$ Then does the following hold?

> $$R\left(\bigcap_{j=0}^{m-1} S_j \right) \subseteq \bigcap_{j=0}^{m-1} R(S_j)$$

It is easily proven that it holds if $R$ is a mapping.

Image is defined as

> $R(S) = \{v \in V|\exists u \in S|(u, v) \in R\}$

Comment: The very same proof works for relations. Really all you need to show is that for relations $S,T\subseteq U\times V$, if $S\subseteq T$ then $R(S)\subseteq R(T)$. A better notation for range of $S\subseteq U\times V$ is $S[U]$.

Comment: @BrianO In my proof for the mapping case I used the fact that $\nexists u_0, u_1|f(u_0) = f(u_1) \land u_0 \neq u_1$. I don't know how to extend that to relations.

Comment: If $v\in R(S)$ and $S\subseteq T$, then there is $u\in U$ with $(u,v)\in S$. Thus $v\in R(S)$. So $R(S)\subseteq R(T)$. Now given those $S_j$, $\bigcap_j S_j \subseteq S_k$, so $R(\bigcap_j S_j) \subseteq R(S_k)$, for any $k$ with $0\le k<m$. The result follows (why?)